# How many times should I rotate the gear wheels?

Tags: tiny-bang-story

I'm at level 3 in the tree at floor 3. I should rotate a gear wheel in an Astrolabe to line up 3 gear wheel. I tried many times, but I can't. How can I fix it?
I fill the guide circle, but it doesn't help too.

Comment: Have you tried using a walkthrough? http://www.gamezebo.com/2011/04/29/tiny-bang-story-walkthrough-cheats-strategy-guide/

Comment: @TheFaster Yes and I can do it. Now can I answer it my self?

Comment: Sure, go ahead :)